# Cummulative SUM based on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with values like this:

[image]

I want to get cumulative sum based on the `ID` and `year`, so it should return an output like this i.e for id- 1 and year 2010 the sum of records will be 2.
                            id-2 and year 2010 the sum of records will be 1 and 
                             id- 2 and for year 2011 it will be 1+1 = 2 i.e i require a running total for each id in ascending order based upon year.

similarly for id =3 Sum will be 1 , for id 4 will be 1 based on the year. for 5 it will be 3 for yr 2014 , for 2015 it will be sum of count previous yr + sum of count current yr i.e it will be 3 + 1 = 4 and for year 2016 it will be 3+ 1+1 = 5. Hence what is to be done. Could someone please help?

[image]

Comment: I want a question where the asker shows some effort

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I have added more comments- @honeyBadger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to make thinks more complicated than they need to be...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    [Year] INT NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (ID, Year) VALUES
    (1, 2010), (1, 2010), (2, 2010), (2, 2011), 
    (3, 2012), (4, 2013), (5, 2014), (5, 2014),
    (5, 2014), (5, 2015), (5, 2016);

--=======================================

SELECT
    tdg.ID,
    tdg.Year,
    RunningCount = SUM(tdg.Cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY tdg.ID ORDER BY tdg.Year ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM (   
    SELECT td.ID, td.Year, Cnt = COUNT(1)
    FROM #TestData td
    GROUP BY td.ID, td.Year
    ) tdg;
```

Results...

```
ID          Year        RunningCount
----------- ----------- ------------
1           2010        2
2           2010        1
2           2011        2
3           2012        1
4           2013        1
5           2014        3
5           2015        4
5           2016        5
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one of them, with an inner query:

```
create table #table_name
(
    UserID int,
    Year int
)
INSERT INTO #table_name (UserID, Year)
VALUES
    (1, 2010)
    ,(1,2010)
    ,(2,2010)
    ,(2,2011)
    ,(3,2012)
    ,(4,2013)
    ,(5,2014)
    ,(5,2014)
    ,(5,2014)
    ,(5,2015)
    ,(5,2016)

SELECT 
    UserID
    ,YEAR
    ,(SELECT COUNT(Year) FROM #table_name WHERE Year <= tt.Year AND UserID = tt.UserID)
FROM 
    #table_name AS tt
GROUP BY UserID, Year
```

you can also use [row number over](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) (edit : see below answer for this technique, I think it is a little bit too complicated for such a simple task). The query above returns your required output

```
+--------+------+-------+
| UserID | Year | COUNT |
+--------+------+-------+
|      1 | 2010 |     2 |
|      2 | 2010 |     1 |
|      2 | 2011 |     2 |
|      3 | 2012 |     1 |
|      4 | 2013 |     1 |
|      5 | 2014 |     3 |
|      5 | 2015 |     4 |
|      5 | 2016 |     5 |
+--------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Could you plaese help me in how to do this with row_number

Comment: You can use the select query by ttallierchio down below. Just replace `your_table` with `#table_name` and `id` with `UserID`

Answer (score 1):

this is more nesting than I would like, and I feel there is a better way to do this with maybe only one windows function but I can't get past not having a unique row for your data.

```
SELECT id,
year ,sum(c) OVER (
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year rows unbounded preceding
    )
FROM (
SELECT id,
    year,
    count(rn) c
FROM (
    SELECT id,
        year,
        row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY year
            ) AS rn
    FROM your_table -- you will need to change this to your table
    ) a
GROUP BY id,
    year
) a
```

what we do is first build the data with a row number so now everything is unique, after that we then do a count on that unique row number and do windows function to do a running total for the count of rows by year.